# Highcharts - change series color on MouseOver

Tags: highcharts, linechart

I know this question has been asked before and I have used heavily a lot of the answers provided by others but am still not 100% the way there.

I want all series lines to be grey and one mouseOver of the line, "turn on" their color, on mouseout revert back to grey.

Ive got this partially working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/matthewnye/f3Wq2/3/) however there are some obvious issues:

1. I know, Ive hardcoded the series array position. I couldnt figure out how to determine what series the mouse was on. Whats the best way to do this?

   ```
    plotOptions: {
           series: {
               events: {
                   mouseOver: function() {chart.series[0].graph.attr('stroke', '#0000FF');
                       $report.html('Moused over')
                       .css('color', 'green');
                   },
                   mouseOut: function() {chart.series[0].graph.attr('stroke', '#C0C0C0');
                       $report.html('Moused out')
                       .css('color', 'red');
                   }
               }
           }
   }
   ```
2. Mouseout isnt triggered until the cursor leaves the chart area. How do I track mouse events more precisely for series lines?

Any improvement to my current code is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
 this.graph.attr('stroke', '#0000FF');
```

instead of hard coding a series:
http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/f3Wq2/5/

I had something similar going a while back, using checkboxes rather than mouseover events. Just in case there's anything in it that's helpful:
http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/57SR9/21/

Comment: that works great, thanks. Any idea why the mouseout event isnt triggered until you go off the chart area?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this example may be the solution for the mouseout issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-mouseover-no-sticky/

This paramter may be what you need:

```
stickyTracking: false,
```

And in the docs:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.mouseOut