# Highcharts: Change series colour on hover; revert back to original colour at mouseOut

Tags: colors, highcharts, mouseover

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277127/highcharts-change-series-color-on-mouseover), but my chart has different colour for each series. What I want to achieve is to "highlight" a series to a certain colour (say, #0000FF) on mouseOver, and then revert back to its original colour at mouseOut. The solution provided in that question does not work here since the series have different colours to start with. An example of my situation is given [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f3Wq2/12/), where the solution suggested for the other question is to modify series event:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {                      
                        this.graph.attr('stroke', '#0000FF');
                        $report.html('Moused over: ' + this.name)
                        .css('color', 'green');
                    },
                    mouseOut: function() {
                        this.graph.attr('stroke', '#C0C0C0');
                        $report.html('Moused out')
                        .css('color', 'red');
                    }
                }
            }
    },
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When returning back to original color use `this.color`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/275/

Comment: Thanks! It's rather inconvenient there isn't a resource detailing the `this` object.

Comment: It would be really huge ref I think - I just use always `console.log` on this object and all args in I need something which isn't documented (not only in Highcharts).

Comment: I have used it too, but some objects are functions and console log doesn't show what they really do...