# Highcharts Change column color on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

It seems like this should be simple, but I cannot figure it out and nothing in the API documentation seems to be working.  I want to change the color of a single column when that column is hovered.

I have tried setting each point in the data to have a hover state with `colorFill`, but to no avail, i have also tried setting it in `plotOptions` in the `column` attribute

Here is a little something to help: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/DMcQ3/

Tried this: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.marker.states.hover.fillColor
Tried this: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.states.hover.marker.fillColor
Both did not work.  Not sure what else to do.

I found this: [Highcharts: changing color on hover ranking chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634818/highcharts-changing-color-on-hover-ranking-chart) but it changes the whole series, not just the current point/column.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You were almost there, but you want to set `color` and not `fillColor` (and not on the marker)-- I added this to the chart declaration:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#000000'                                                           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And removed the `states` stuff from the column data, that seems to work in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/zDSeR/).

And, yes, that's not very clear in the documentation ...

Comment: Thanks!  They need to update their documentation, I would have never guessed color would go there: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.states.hover

Comment: Looks like you can also use borderColor there and probably other options.