# Highcharts: Stacked Column increase borderWidth on select state

Tags: javascript, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/sgrg93/4d08tj96/3/

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    allowPointSelect: true,
    stacking: 'normal',
    borderWidth: 8,      //This is giving spaces in between which I want to avoid
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      color: 'white',
      style: {
        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
      }
    },
    states: {
      select: {
        color: null,
        borderWidth: 8,      //border width should increase on select
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above fiddle, I have defined the select states for the stacks. There are spaces between the stacks because of borderWidth: 8 and default borderColor : '#FFFFFF'. I don't want the spaces between the stacks initially (i.e. without doing any selection) and the borderWidth should increase only when I select any stack. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a tricky one. I tested out a few different configurations based on some questions I found elsewhere on Stack Overflow (see below), and it seems you can do the following:

- If you change "states" to "events," you can have the border size change on the "mouseOver" and "mouseOut" states, but not for the "select" state.

  ```
  events: {
      mouseOver: function () {
         this.update({
            borderWidth: 8
         });                
     },
     mouseOut: function () {
         this.update({
             borderWidth: 0
         }); 
     }}
  }
  ```
- If you change "select" to "hover" in your "states" clause, you can change the border color (`borderColor`) if you have the width defined elsewhere, but you can't change the width (using `borderWidth`).

Here are the questions I referenced for this response:

- [Highcharts: changing color on hover ranking chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634818/highcharts-changing-color-on-hover-ranking-chart)
- [Highcharts Change column color on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146049/highcharts-change-column-color-on-hover)

I know this doesn't precisely solve your issue, but I hope the information I found will be helpful for you.