# HighCharts: 3D Column Chart change borderColor on select

Tags: javascript, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/5ojcppsc/

```
allowPointSelect: true,
borderWidth: 2,
depth: 25,
states: {
  select: {
    color: "black",
    borderColor: "red"
  }
}
```

I am not able to change borderColor of 3D columns on select. Is there any way to achieve this? Also I want to change the borderWidth on select.

PS I want to avoid using this.update() in select callback event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the select event and directly manipulate on the SVG element.

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/h6etesbp/

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    allowPointSelect: true,
    borderWidth: 2,
    depth: 25,
    point: {
      events: {
        select:function() {
          var p = this;
          setTimeout(function() { 
          p.graphic.attr({
            'stroke': 'red',
            'stroke-width': 2
          })
          },1);
        }
      }
    },
  }
},
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using the callback functions. Thanks anyway for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found and answered a similar question a few days ago that you may find useful:

[Highcharts: Stacked Column increase borderWidth on select state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930997/highcharts-stacked-column-increase-borderwidth-on-select-state/).

I don't see any reason why the options would differ for 3D charts.

Try it out and let me know whether this works for you. I can work up a fiddle to further research what you're seeking if this question doesn't get you where you need to be.